# What is being defined in this class definition

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I am learning unreal engine and I know a little about C++. However, I am not entirely sure what is going on in this line of code. Can someone explain to me like i'm 5?

```
class ESCAPEROOM_API UWorldPosition : public UActorComponent
```

We are defining the function as UActorComponent which is understood, but not sure what is going on in this piece:

```
class ESCAPEROOM_API UWorldPosition
```

The rest of the code,

```
#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "Components/ActorComponent.h"
#include "WorldPosition.generated.h"


UCLASS( ClassGroup=(Custom), meta=(BlueprintSpawnableComponent) )
class ESCAPEROOM_API UWorldPosition : public UActorComponent <==========
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public: 
    // Sets default values for this component's properties
    UWorldPosition();

protected:
    // Called when the game starts
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;

public: 
    // Called every frame
    virtual void TickComponent(float DeltaTime, ELevelTick TickType, FActorComponentTickFunction* ThisTickFunction) override;

        
};
```

Comment: This is not a function definition. This is the definition of a class called `UWorldPosition` that is derived from a base class called `UActorComponent`

Comment: What is the name `ESCAPEROOM_API ` for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> We are defining the function as UActorComponent

Not true, you are defining a class `UWorldPosition` which is publically derived from another class `UActorComponent`.

The `ESCAPEROOM_API` part is not standard C++ but it is likely to be a macro whose purpose is to export that class from a shared library. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/using-dllimport-and-dllexport-in-cpp-classes?view=msvc-160).

Since you are beginner at C++ you'd probably find learning about it easier with a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). C++ is a complex language.

Answer (score 1):

(*Too long for a comment*.)

Without knowing a thing about unreal engines, but having browsed C++ code before, this is what I see on a first quick read, which tells me that the code defines class `UWorldPosition` derived from `UActorComponent` with the purpose of overriding two virtual functions defined in the base.

```
class ... UWorldPosition : public UActorComponent
{
    ... BeginPlay() override;

    ... TickComponent(...) override;      
};
```

Those are the parts left after skipping over the all-uppercase macros (`UCLASS`, `ESCAPEROOM_API`) which must be some non-standard implementation details/attributes, boilerplate code (`GENERATE_BODY`, default constructor), and less interesting or redundant bits (`#include`, `virtual`).